# ASP.NET 4.0 site displaying error - ISAPI "Restriction" column is missing

Tags: asp.net, .net, isapi, restriction

My ASP.NET (running with .NET 4.0) site is throwing an error.

Error:

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.

I've tried doing the steps in this article.  I didn't have a CGI/ISAPI option, so I clicked on "ISAPI Filters".  The "Restriction" column seems to be missing.

http://frejnorling.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/configure-iis-7-5-to-manage-asp-net-4-0-web-pages/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place. You have opened the "ISAPI Filters" feature, not the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" feature:

[image: IIS Manager]

Open that feature and you will see the restrictions column.

Comment: I don't have that option.  I wonder if it's because I have Windows 7 Home Premium Edition?

Comment: You have to click on the server name, not the site name, before the option will appear.

Comment: Side tip: I did notice that Windows Authentication is not in Windows Home Premium though.  So I ended up upgrading to Windows Ultimate for that reason.